# NSArray causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsarray

I have a problem with using an NSArray to populate a UITableView.  I'm sure I'm doing something daft but I can't figure it out.  When I try and do a simple count I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS, which I know is because I am trying to read from a memory location that doesn't exist.

My .h file has this:

```
@interface AnalysisViewController : UITableViewController 
{
StatsData *statsData;
NSArray *SectionCellLabels;
}
```

My .m has this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
NSLog(@"AnalysisViewController:viewWillAppear");

// Step 1 - Create the labels array
SectionCellLabels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"analysis 1",
                     @"analysis 2",
                     @"analysis 3", nil];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSLog(@"AnalysisViewController:cellForRowAtIndexPath");

// Check for reusable cell first, use that if it exists
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView    
              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

// If there is no reusable cell of this type, create a new one
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
             initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
             reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"] autorelease];
}

    /******* The line of code below causes the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error *********/
NSLog(@"%d",[SectionCellLabels count]);

return cell;
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
SectionCellLabels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"analysis 1",
                     @"analysis 2",
                     @"analysis 3", nil];
```

Your array is autoreleased, so at the end of the method it's probably not accessible anymore.

To fix that, simply append a `retain` message like this:

```
SectionCellLabels = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:..., nil] retain];
```

And be sure to `release` the array in another place, like your `dealloc` method.

One extra tip, you may want to use names with the first character in lowercase, so they don't appear to be classes. You can even notice that this confused StackOverflow's highlighting.

Comment: Thanks very much for that.  I am really struggling with the retain/release memory management aspects of Objective C.  I.e. How do you know when its auto released and when it isn't? :-s

Comment: Hey @hydev, basically when the method starts with "alloc" or "new" or they contain "copy" then the object returned is of your ownership (meaning you have to release it when not needed). All the other methods return autoreleased objects, you don't have to worry about releasing them. But also, they may not be available later like in your case. Be sure to read the memory management guide from Apple to understand better: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: @sidyll, thanks this solved the problem that i was struggling with for an hour, surprisingly it didn't throw any error in xcode 3. But I have a question i declared SectionCellLabels as  a retain property in the header file @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *SectionCellLabels; even then I have to do retain when i populate the value that is something I am not able to understand. If you have any idea please let me know.

Comment: @Yogesh: Hmm, declaring a property doesn't remove the need to initialize the array. Have you done so? Also, I don't think you need to set an NSMutableArray. Probably a read-only property is enough to access the array and modify its contents.

Comment: @sidyll: Oh ya i am initializing the array. My question was that when i declare the property as "retain" then when I initialize do i have to again say "retain"? Let me check on the other part where If i do read-only everything works as expected. Thanks for responding to my comment.

Comment: @Yogesh: Yes, on initialization you have to retain it (and release on your class dealloc). Also, while initializing you generally want to access the ivar directly, as the setters and getters may not be "ready" yet. So if I got it right, this behaviour is correct. You initialize the array, and from that point on any something in  `object.array = something` doesn't need to be retained.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SectionCellLabels = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"analysis 1",
                     @"analysis 2",
                     @"analysis 3", nil] retain];
```